# Plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Below is my dataset and I want to plot variables `states`, `o7`, `cas`, and `df` over time

```
year    states  o7  cas df
1989     151    117 35  16
1990     150    158 27  12
1991     150    194 43  12
1992     150    173 38  9
1993     151    169 35  14
1994     153    169 23  9
1995     153    158 22  8
1996     153    157 18  6
1997     153    214 18  11
1998     154    186 17  5
1999     154    222 16  7
2000     155    210 20  4
2001     154    210 19  2
2002     155    231 17  2
2003     155    268 18  1
2004     155    236 16  3
2005     155    263 19  1
2006     155    238 17  5
2007     155    284 16  3
2008     155    318 20  4
2009     155    295 18  5
2010     155    330 20  4
2011     155    312 16  3
```

I use `ggplot2` package to do this

```
ggplot(dat, aes(year, o7)) +
  geom_line()
```

However, I fail to plot other variables in the same plot.

- How do I plot other variables in the data? And how do I assign them
  new labels (within ggplot)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is largely recommended to use the `melt` function from `reshape2` package when you want to plot several columns in the same ggplot.

```
# df = your example
require(reshape2)
df_melt = melt(df, id = "year")

ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

As mentionned by @Nathan Day, columns have widely different ranges, using a `facet_wrap` could be a possibility :

```
ggplot(df_melt, aes(x = year, y = value, color = variable)) + geom_point() + 
facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, looks great. One thing: how to switch to lines with different shapes instead of dots with different colors – I'm colorblind..

Comment: switching to lines is easy geom_lines(), but how to get them in different shapes?

Comment: You can add `linetype = variable` inside the `aes` of the `ggplot` object if you use `geom_line` instead of `geom_point`. Using `shape = variable` in the `aes` and then using `geom_point` will modify the shape of points.

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot` is predicated on layers of graphics. If you want to include multiple variables all plotted against `time`, you will need a unique layer for each:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = o7)) +
 geom_line() +
 geom_line(aes(y = cas)) +
 geom_line(aes(y = df))
```

Keep in mind that all layers in a ggplot function (ie. `geom_line`) are trying to inherit the `aes(...)` set by `ggplot(aes(...))`. This behavior is controlled by a parameter `inherit.aes =` which by default is set to `TRUE`

Because it looks like your columns have widely different ranges you might be better off using another option like `aes(colour = ?, shape = ?)` fro map `cas` and `df`. Something to play around with for maximum visual impact.